# Vector filled with different object

Tags: c++, vector

I've some trouble with the following task.

At first I had a vector with just one type of objects(bikes).

I could use this objects to put them into a class and used a function to print out the brands and model of those bikes like this:

```
for (Bike* b1  : vecBikes) {
        b1->printBrandModel();
    }
```

My class's name is Bike.

From this class I derived two new classes, which are MTB for Mountain Bikes and E_Bikes.
I read the file again and stored them either as MTB or E_Bike objects into my vector like this:

```
while (inputFile >> brand >> model >> modelyear >> price >> type) {

    if (type == "MTB") {
        vecBikes.push_back(new MTB(brand, model, modelyear, price));
    }
    else {
       inputFile >> energy; 
       vecBikes.push_back(new E_Bike(brand, model, modelyear, price, energy));
    }
    getline(inputFile, buffer);
}
```

Now I want to do pretty the same. But this time I want to print eihter MTB's or E_Bikes from this vector.

Maybe a dynamic_cast is the way to go but I'm a complete beginner on this subject and all those examples books and websites can't help me somehow.
I hope you can help me out on this ;-)

Comment: First of all please format your code correctly.

Comment: You can do the exact same `for` loop as long as `printBrandModel` is declared `virtual` in `Bike` and is declared `override` in the derived classes

Comment: Also show more code, it's hard to tell if you're on the right path or not without seeing at least your class declarations. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: Oh, Okay I'm sorry... There is quite some Code but I can put it here

Comment: @Kai [MCVE] with emphasis on __Minimal__, of course this requires some work from you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic_cast for determining the object type as below:

```
for (Bike* b1  : vecBikes) {
    if(dynamic_cast<MTB*>(b1) != nullptr) {
            b1->print_MBT();
    } else if (dynamic_cast<E_Bikes*>(b1) != nullptr) {
            b1->print_E_Bikes();
    } else cout << "error" << endl;  
}
```

Moreover, if you define a pure virtual method `printBrandModel` in your base class, you can(must) implement it as desired in derived classes. So you can use the first code without determining the instance belongs to which class.

```
for (Bike* b1  : vecBikes) {
     b1->printBrandModel();
}
```

Comment: The dynamic_cast method is ugly, inheritance should be used for that as you suggest in the econd part of your answer. It's a classical text book example.

Comment: @MichaelWalz He, knows that and does not now how to use that (dynamic_cast)

Comment: I think your `print_printBrandModel` function name has a bit of a typo in it.

Comment: @BonjeFir -> If I want to print just the MTB's from the vector (and ignore the E_Bikes) I can just use the first "if-Part" rihgt? Some how this is resulting in a loop printing my vector over and over. The action takes place in the last part of the code I added -.-

Comment: @Kai Yes, You can iterate over whole of your vector and operate(printing or something else) on instances just with MBT type. I do not understand second part of your comment exactly...

Comment: @Kai please do not post whole of your code... just what can clarify your question...

Comment: @BonjeFir Thank you very much for your help! Now I got it running as I wanted and since you explained it to me, I'm finally understanding, what's going on;-)